# Woocommerce product variation selection with buttons instead dropdown menu?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am new to wordpress.
I am creating a ecommerge website with wordpress 4.5(latest) + woocommerge 2.5.5(latest) + storefront theme.

I have a product with 2 variations with different prices.

When I select a variation from dropdown menu displaying variation price under dropdown.

Product detail page with 2 variations shown as below:

[image: Default product displaying like this]

I want to select variantions with buttons instead dropdown, and update product price on product page instead show below of dropdown.

If I create different products for each variantion and add custom html for buttons and link each variation products with each other, this works but this is very painful.

**How to make variations selection with buttons instead dropdown shown as below picture**

[image: I want to variation selection like this]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was made variantion selection with buttons instead select box with javascript plugin.

I created a plugin and included a js file to product page that creates buttons for each variant at product page and hide select box.

Pros:

Not changed any file of wordpress core, woocommerce and storefront theme.

myplugin.php

```
define('MYPLUGIN__VERSION', '1.0');
function variant_selection_with_buttons() {
    if (is_product()) {
        #TODO serve .min.js on production
        $js_file = plugins_url('/js/variant-selection-with-buttons.js', __FILE__);

        wp_register_script(
            'variant_selection_with_buttons_js',
            $js_file,
            array('jquery'),
            MYPLUGIN__VERSION,
            true
        );

        wp_enqueue_script('variant_selection_with_buttons_js');
    }
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'variant_selection_with_buttons');
```

js/variations-selection-with-buttons.js

```
;(function($, window, document, undefined){
    var variations = $('.variations_form').data('product_variations'),
    requiredVals = {},
    selectedVariation;

    $('.woocommerce-variation').remove();
    $('table.variations').hide();

    $(variations).each(function(i, item){
        var variationSlug;
        $.each(item['attributes'], function(key, value){
            variationSlug = value;
            return;
        });

        requiredVals[variationSlug] = {
            'price_html': item['price_html'],
            'variation_description': item['variation_description'],
        };
    });

    var $variationChangerCon = $('<div/>', {
        'id': 'variationChangerCon',
        'style': 'margin-bottom:5px',
    });

    $variationChangerCon.append('<div class="variationBtns"/>');

    $('table.variations').find('select option').each(function(index){
        var $option = $(this);
        if (!$option.val()) return;

        if ($option.is(':selected')){
            selectedVariation =$option.val();
        }

        var $button = $('<a/>', {
            'class': 'variation-btn single_add_to_cart_button button btn-info PvariationLink',
            'text': $option.text(),
            'style': 'margin-right:2px;',
        });

        $button.attr('data-slug', $option.val());
        $variationChangerCon.find('.variationBtns').append($button);

    });

    $variationChangerCon.append('<div class="variationDesc"/>');
    $variationChangerCon.insertBefore('.entry-summary div[itemprop="description"]');

    $('div.product').on('click', '.variation-btn', function(){
        var $this = $(this),
            item = requiredVals[$this.data('slug')];
            itemDesc = requiredVals[$this.data('slug')];

        $('.variation-btn').removeClass('disabled');
        $this.addClass('disabled');
        $('table.variations select').val($this.data('slug')).trigger('change')

        $('.entry-summary div[itemprop="offers"] p.price')
        .html(item['price_html'])
        $variationChangerCon.find('.variationDesc').html(item['variation_description']);
    });


    if (selectedVariation) {
        $('.variationBtns .variation-btn[data-slug="'+ selectedVariation +'"]').trigger('click');

    } else {
        /*
            If default variation not selected in admin pane
            `selectedVariation` become undefined . So select first variation/
        */

        $('.variationBtns .variation-btn:eq(0)').trigger('click');

    }
})( jQuery, window, document, undefined );
```

Comment: It seems that the line `$variationChangerCon.insertBefore('.entry-summary div[itemprop="description"');` is missing a closing square bracket (`]`)?